# How to select samples from a 2-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to select some cells in a 2D NumPy matrix according to a list. However, the following code

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = [(1,1), (1,2), (2,1)]
a[b]
```

raises the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-a8bd6862e58c> in <module>()
      1 a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
      2 b = [(1,1), (1,2), (2,1)]
----> 3 a[b]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

However, the correct result needs to be `(5, 6, 8)`. I could have done it using the following piece of code, however, I wonder if there are any more efficient ways of doing this (in a `numpy` vectorized fashion)?

The code which works:

```
map(lambda (x): a[x], b)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*transpose* `b` with `zip`, and then use it as index:

```
a[tuple(zip(*b))]
# array([5, 6, 8])
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
row, col = zip(*b)
a[row, col]
```